# Using Max and Sum in the same query

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to get the the best selling product in all sales, and I'm using the following query:

```
SELECT Max(Sum(sold_mount)), 
       product_code 
FROM   sold_ items 
GROUP  BY product_code;
```

and it's returning "not a single-group group function"

it's possible to use max and sum in the same query?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend writing this as:

```
SELECT SUM(sold_mount), product_code
FROM sold_ items
GROUP BY product_code
ORDER BY SUM(sold_amount) DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY;
```